# DOMDocument Class

Tags: php

I have this function. Function generate errors with DOMDocument Class.

Someone knows why?
Thanks for help

```
function getTitleAndLinks($content)
{
    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);

    $links = [];
    $container = $doc->getElementById("content");
    $arr = $container->getElementsByTagName("a");
  
    foreach($arr as $item)
    {
        $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");
        $title =  $item->getAttribute("title");

        if($item->hasAttribute('rel') && $item->getAttribute('rel') == 'bookmark') {    
            $links[] = [
                'href' => $href,
                'title' => $title
            ];
        }
    }

    return $links;
}
```

I have arrors like this:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in /home/pc47230/domains/pc47230.wsbpoz.solidhost.pl/public_html/projektkoncowy/functions/functions.php on line 64
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null in /home/pc47230/domains/pc47230.wsbpoz.solidhost.pl/public_html/projektkoncowy/functions/functions.php:69 Stack trace: #0 /home/pc47230/domains/pc47230.wsbpoz.solidhost.pl/public_html/projektkoncowy/index.php(12): getTitleAndLinks(false) #1 {main} thrown in /home/pc47230/domains/pc47230.wsbpoz.solidhost.pl/public_html/projektkoncowy/functions/functions.php on line 69

Comment: _“Someone knows why?”_ - the error message already told you that, no? _“DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input”_ - so $content appears to be empty, so check what you are passing in the place where you call this function …

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting $content from this function:

```
function curl_get_wp_login( $login_user, $login_pass, $login_url, $visit_url, $http_agent, $cookie_file ){

if( !function_exists( 'curl_init' ) || ! function_exists( 'curl_exec' )){
        $m = "cUrl is not vailable in you PHP server.";
        echo $m;
    }

    // Preparing postdata for wordpress login
    $data = "log=". $login_user ."&pwd=" . $login_pass . "&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=" . $visit_url;

    // Intialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Url to use
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );

    // Set the cookies for the login in a cookie file.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );

    // Set SSL to false
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/sni238399cloudflaresslcom.crt");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $http_agent );

    // Maximum time cURL will wait for get response. in seconds
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 36000 );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );

    // Return or echo the execution
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

    // Set Http referer.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url );

    // Post fields to the login url
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Save the return in a variable
    $content = curl_exec ($ch);
    /*
    ** if you need to visit another url ,you can do it here.
    ** curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'a new url address or a file download url' );
    ** $content = curl_exec ($ch);
    */

    // Close the cURL.
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $content;

}
```

That returns bool(false) and I don't know why.